# Testing: mocha + typescript + webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, mocha.js

I'm using TypeScript, Mocha (with mocha-typescript plugin) for testing and WebPack for build in my application.

Recently I decided to add DefinePlugin for WebPack to separate configs for prod and dev environments:

```
import { AppSettings as DevSettings } from './appSettings.dev'
import { AppSettings as ProdSettings } from './appSettings.prod'

declare var __ENVIRONMENT__: string;

let settings = __ENVIRONMENT__ === 'prod' ? ProdSettings : DevSettings

export let AppSettings = settings;
```

In snippet above there is a global variable `__ENVIRONMENT__` , which helps to choose settings I want to use. This variable is defined in webpack.config.js as follows:

```
module.exports = function(env) {
    var config = {
        // ...
        plugins: [
            new ExtendedDefinePlugin({
                __ENVIRONMENT__: env === 'prod' ? 'prod' : 'dev',
            })
        ]
        // ...
    }

    return config;
}
```

So I change tests execution in package.json to

```
"test": "webpack --env=dev && mocha --recursive"
```

If I call "test", mocha throw error (webpack builds files correctly):

```
ReferenceError: __ENVIRONMENT__ is not defined
```

Testing watcher also won't work:

```
"test-watch": "mocha-typescript-watch"
```

throwing error "Exited with 1".

Is it possible to bring them work together? Or shall I use another way for testing?

Comment: DefinePlugin should literally substitute `__ENVIRONMENT__` with 'prod' or 'dev' in the build output - are you sure that substitution is working for the browser?

Comment: @Catalyst, yes it is. But it's not a root cause of this circumstance - I just didn't understand fully concepts of mocha and webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I eventually got I was using it in wrong manner.

It's more correctly to set up variable related to Node in webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(env) {
    var config = {
        // ...
        plugins: [
            new ExtendedDefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    'NODE_ENV': env === 'prod' ? 'prod' : 'dev',
                }
            })
        ]
        // ...
    }

    return config;
}
```

And use it whenever necessary like:

```
declare var process: any;

export let AppSettings = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod' ? ProdSettings : DevSettings;
```

Therefore my Mocha tests run well (because they are being executed in Node, not in browser).

Comment: I don't get it what makes your code work. NODE_ENV? as a string? is "process.env" something that node can identify?